# Relations and Sets

Tags: schema, primary-key, relational-theory, cardinality-estimates

From my understanding, `One = {1,2,3,4,5...20}`, and then if `Two = {1}`, then `One` won't map into `Two`. On that token, how come the answer is `d` instead of `a`?

[image]

Comment: What about if `One[this] = {1,1,1,1,...,1}`?

Comment: I'll just elaborate a bit on ypercubeᵀᴹ question. We know that One(this, that, other) have a cardinality of 20. What cardinality is One[this] guaranteed to have? What cardinality does ypercubeᵀᴹ:s example of `One[this]` have?

Comment: OHHHH, so the cardinality doesn't matter; as long as One contains the elements within 2. It's not quantity; it's quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation `One` has 20 tuples. Note that the key of One is `that` (it is underlined), so we are sure that each tuple has a different values for `that`, so the cardinality of `One[that]` is 20, but it could have the same (or different) values for `this`, so we know with certainty only that it has *at least* a value for `this` (see the example of @ypercubeᵀᴹ).

Since we know that `One[this]` ⊆ `Two[tweedledee]`, we know that `Two` must have at least one tuple, and possibly more. Note that the fact the `tweedledee` is a not a key of relation `Two` means that there could be many tuples with the same value of this attribute.